# Kernel of an infinite dimensional upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, positive-definite

Is it true that an upper triangular infinite-dimensional Matrix (not bi-infinite) with positive diagonal elements only has zero as its kernel?
I know that for invertibility I would need a lower bound of the matrix norm, but is the above sufficient for the kernel to be only zero?
Would also be thankful for literature tips.

Comment: kernel in what space? because it is easy to build a counterexample

Comment: Assume the matrix with real entries $A$ is bounded in $l_2$. Might there be a non-zero element in $l_2$ for which $Ay=0$?

Comment: Yes, just take a bidiagonal with 1 on the diagonal and -2 on the upper diagonal. Then (1, 1/2, 1/4, ...) is in the kernel

Comment: Thank you a lot!